# Facebook Connect with GWT and App Engine (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, facebook

Discovered a problem with connecting all together - Facebook, GWT and App Engine.

I need to authenticate user on my web site hosted on App Engine (Java) that uses GWT. After authentication, some information should be passed to server from facebook - like profile information, user list, etc.

Currently am trying to use facebook4gwt and authentication works fine, and I can obtain all needed information on client side, but can not transfer facebook session to server, particularly, obtain Facebook cookies for [session verification](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Verifying_The_Signature).

Could anyone suggest any good solution for this? Probably, it would make sense to get rid of facebook4gwt and do everything on server side.

Comment: I have just noticed that it is possible to login on stackoverflow using facebook. Is facebook supporting OpenID? How is it done here?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the [gwt-facebook](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-facebook/) library for one year to authenticate users of my application on App Engine. When a user is already logged into Facebook, and has already authorized my application, I can automatically get the `access_token` in GWT and send it to the server which can then do the hard work (data syncing) with [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) library.